# How to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded through InvokeHttp nifi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I send the URL encoded data through InvokeHTTP using nifi.

I am trying to get the data from mongo and after getting I am calling an api through `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` My structure as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

Problem which I am facing I am trying to replaceText processor to get motify the data

But it seems its not replacing anything rather it sending the exact data

`{ '{"match_id": 3626}': '' }`

Here is the configuration of replaceText

[image: Replace Text configuration]